# Redirecting multiple routes in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on an express app and am new to the framework.  I have a few routes I'd like to redirect to one without doing something like:

```
var router = require("express").Router();

router.all("/route", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/repetitive");
});

router.all("/route2", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/repetitive");
});
```

This is a contrived example, but I'm looking for a way to have many routes redirect to `/repetitive` without writing lots of `router.all`s , but I don't see a way in the docs. Is passing a regex to `router.all` an option and if so is that the best practice for express? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following?

```
var r = function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/repetitive");
}

var routes = ["/route", "/route2"];
for (var i in routes)
    router.all(routes[i], r);
```

or if names follow a regular expression pattern:

```
router.all(/\/route\d*/, function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/repetitive");
});
```

The above will match "/route" optionally followed by a number.

Comment: I went with the regex so I could do something like `router.all(/(route|route2)/)` .... Thanks!